# Unable to run localhost on node.js project

Tags: mysql, express, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, dotenv

I keep running into this error when I try to run the server or seed my database:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
> errno: -61,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 3306,
> fatal: true
> }

here is how I configured my connection:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

require('dotenv').config();

// create connection to our db
const sequelize = process.env.JAWSDB_URL
  ? new Sequelize(process.env.JAWSDB_URL)
  : new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PW, {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      port: 3306
    });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

and here is how I set up my server file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

const sess = {
  secret: 'Super secret secret',
  cookie: {}, 
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize
  })
};

app.use(session(sess));

const hbs = exphbs.create({});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(require('./controllers/'));

sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Now listening'));
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it possible that your process.env.PORT is set to 3306 by sequelize, so then when you try to run the app, it is using the same port? Maybe I'm off base, but if it were me, I'd try changing const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001; to const PORT =  3001;  to see what happens.

Comment: Also, are you sure your database is running?

Comment: @Maiya you were spot on, I restarted my database and everything works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: cool. what a relief :)